# Compositing html code in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering

I am currently trying to render a table from data in React, and I have this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

// Column component - represents columns in the table
export default class Table extends Component {
setHtmlHead(data) {
    var html = "";
    for (var property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            html += "<th>" + data[property] + "</th>";
        }
    }
    return "<tr>" + html + "</tr>";
}

setHtmlBody(data) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        html += "<tr>";
        for (var property in row) {
            if (row.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
               html += "<td>" + row[property] + "</td>";
            }
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    return html;
}

render() {
    return (
        <table className='table table-bordered'>
            <thead dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.setHtmlHead(this.props.data[0]) }} />
            <tbody dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.setHtmlBody(this.props.data.slice(1), "td") }} />
        </table>
    );
}
}
```

As you can see, I am doing this mostly wrong, probably (hopefully?). There has to be a way to dynamically add `<th>`es in the render function, but I cannot figure it out.

I want to be able to do a for loop, like in the `setHtml()` functions above, but instead of appending strings I want to append html-code. Also, probably inside the `render` function?

I want to also be able to do something like `<th><Button /></th>`, and have the `Button` render correctly (`Button` is defined in a different jsx file and renders a button, but if I use strings or `toString()`, it gets converted to `[Object object]`.

So, is there a way to composit html-data in React? I know of `map` but I wasn't able to make it do what I want it to do... especially since I want the last column to be a `Button` so not part of the data (though I guess I could get it there using CSS instead of making it be a column).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read this article: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you would usually do something like this:

```
setHtmlHead(data) {
    var html = [];
    for (var property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            html.push(<th key={property}>{data[property]}</th>);
        }
    }
    return <tr>{html}</tr>;
}
```

And then in the main part

```
<thead>{this.setHtmlHead(this.props.data[0])}</thead>
```

This way you're working with actual objects and not just writing raw HTML out. And if you want a `Button` in the `th` just put it in there.